# How to fetch data when TabView page is selected in SwiftUI

Tags: mvvm, swiftui, tabview

I am trying to fetch a CoreData object when my TabView (page style) gets displayed based on an ID I send to the view from the TabView ForEach.

```
TabView(selection: $tabSelection) {
        ForEach(Array(balloons.enumerated()), id: \.element) { index, balloon in
            BalloonView(balloon: balloon, balloonID: balloon.id)
                .tag(index)
        }
    }
```

So each tab gets the `balloonID` sent correctly to the `BalloonView` then what I have been trying to do on the view is: call my `ViewModel` from `BalloonView` using `.task` that then fetches the CoreData object and puts it in a @Published var that I listen for in the view. (Basicaly a normal MVVM pattern, I think?).

This works fine if I just use a NavigationLink and navigate the view. But when I do it inside the TabView as showed above it's very unstable since it seems this .task is called multiple times and as soon as you slide a little to the page.

I am new to SwiftUI, and I have a sense that the state variable: `$tabSelection` on the TabView could solve it somehow. I just can't figure out how I can call my viewModel and tell it to fetch the CoreData object when the `$tabSection` is changed to whatever ID?

Hope it makes sense, any help is appreciated.

ViewModel:

```
@Published var myBalloon: MyBalloon?    

func getBalloonBy(id: String) {
    myBalloon = coreDataManager.getBalloonFrom(id: id)
}
```

View:

```
@EnvironmentObject var balloonViewModel: BalloonViewModel

if let note = balloonViewModel.myBalloon?.note?.description {
    Text("Note: \(note)")
}

.task {
    balloonViewModel.getBalloonBy(id: balloonID)
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for: `.onChange(of: tabSelection) { [tabSelection] newState in }`?

Comment: Hmm.. not sure? Can I somehow communicate this to my view? Really struggling with understanding the flow of data in SwiftUI compared to UIKit. Would really appreciate an example :)

Comment: It would help if you started with a [mre] that could be edited to show the concept.

Comment: I added more code to the question. This should be all the parts that are related to the question.  The main view that holds the TabView, the View the TabView navigates to, and the ViewModel for that view. :) Or is that too little?

Comment: Ideally, it would be copy/pastable into Xcode -- don't leave the answerer(s) to have to create the boilerplate of the views/objects to surround your code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jnpdx I figured it out. `.onChange(of: tabSelection) { [tabSelection] newState in }` did the trick, since I was now able to call my CoreData function based on the change of page instead on .onAppear